# How to Authorize SignalR Hub Connection using Cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am very new to SignalR and I am trying to authorize connections to the SignalR Hub using Cookie.

Below is the code for my Hub Class;

```
[Authorize]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    ....
}
```

and I've below code in the `Application_Start`

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
```

Where am I supposed to do the Authorization process? Is there any specific event for this?
Or `AuthorizeRequest` method which I can override?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

edit: Sorry I read, Authenticate but you ment Authorize.
YOu can decorate the Hub methods with the PrincipalPermision attribute to Authorize the hub and its methods.

Comment: Can shed some light on how this works? What is the use of `GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();`? Also where can I implement my custom authorization logic?

Comment: That is used for Self hosted SignalR. You should use the ASP.NET authenticate/Authorize pipeline